# Run-Time Check Failure #2: Stack around the variable 'power' was corrupted

Tags: c

I just started using c again and I can't figure out where I currupt the stack.
There are a lot of similar questions but the answer is individual here.
I hope someone can tell me what I did wrong.

The platform is windows, but it's for an OS course so it's supposed to work on XV6 (simplified version of Unix version 6) as well.

I have two structs:

```
struct elem {
    unsigned char power; // the power of this item
    float coef; // the coefficient
};
struct item {
    struct elem* elem;
    struct item* next;
};
```

and I have a global variable:

```
struct item* polynom1;
```

When I debug the following method, at the return statement I get an exception "Run-Time Check Failure #2: Stack around the variable 'power' was corrupted":

```
struct item* readPolynom()
{
    struct item* res = (struct item*)malloc(sizeof(struct item));
    struct item* nextPoly = res;
    unsigned char power;
    float coef;

    res->next = NULL;

    do
    {
        scanf("%hu%f", &power, &coef);

        if (power != 0 || coef != 0)
        {
            nextPoly->elem = (struct elem*) malloc(sizeof(struct elem));
            nextPoly->elem->coef = coef;
            nextPoly->elem->power = power;
            nextPoly->next = (struct item*) malloc(sizeof(struct  item));
            nextPoly = nextPoly->next;
        }
    } while (power != 0 || coef != 0);

    nextPoly = NULL;

    return res;
}
```

The input is: 5 5.5 (enter) 4 4 (enter) 0 0 (enter).
Important - 'res' gets the correct values.

I tried replacing %hu by %hhu / %u as well but I got the same result.
I also tried adding "free(nextPoly);" before "nextPoly = NULL;" - still the same.

thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Simple: `power` is an `unsigned char` and `%hu` tells `scanf` it's an `unsigned short`.

Comment: I'll add this comment to the actual post too. The platform is windows, but it's for an OS course so it's supposed to work on XV6 (simplified version of Unix version 6) as well. immibis - I tried %hhu and %u as well but I got the same result.

Comment: What is the input ? Try to replace `unsigned char power` by `unsigned short power`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the types are mandatory. The input is: 5 5.5 (enter) 4 4 (enter) 0 0 (enter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
scanf("%hu%f", &power, &coef);
```

by

```
int tmppower;
scanf("%hu%f", &tmppower, &coef);
if (tmppower > 255)
{
   printf("Invalid power\n");
   exit(1);
}
power = (char)tmppower;
```